# Escaping plus sign (+) in sheet names

Tags: google-sheets-api

We have a google spreadsheet with a sheet named something like `foo + bar (yay)`. When I try to select data from the sheet using the Java API, I'm getting back an error from Google saying:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Unable to parse range: foo   bar (yay)!A2:Z",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Unable to parse range: foo   bar (yay)!A2:Z",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

The code looks something like this (some details of authentication elided, and translated from Scala)

```java
Sheets s = ... // constructed using HTTP transport & credentials
String range = "'foo + bar (yay)'!A2:Z";
String spreadsheetId = ... // fill in your own
ValueRange values = s.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
```

It's based on the following code example: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample

Notice that the `+` has been replaced by a single space  , as if it were being URL encoded. I tried replacing `+` with `%2B` but I still get an error and it repeats `%2B` back to me as if I meant literally "%2B" - so I don't think it's a matter of URL encoding.

I tried listing the sheet names for this spreadsheet, and I'm getting back a `+` sign in the sheet name, so I don't think that's the problem. Then I tried renaming the sheet to use the word "and" instead of `+`, and my code was able to successfully select the range - thus I'm pretty certain the `+` is the problem. I don't see any description of escaping special characters in the documentation.

I noticed this in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation and tried surrounding the sheet name with single quotes (`"'foo + bar (yay)'"`) but to no avail.

Is there any way I can select this range without renaming the sheet?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your script for replicating the issue? Because from your question, I cannot understand about `https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation and tried surrounding the sheet name with single quotes, but to no avail.`. For example, in my environment, I could confirm that when `'foo + bar (yay)'!A1` is used for the method of "spreadsheets.values.get" in Sheets API, no error occurs and it returns the correct value.

Comment: More information is certainly needed - as well as the code as requested by Tanaike, what method of the API are you calling? The `Try This API` feature [works with no issue](https://imgur.com/ThkKrFY.png).

Comment: Updated with code samples

Comment: What is the Scala library you're using? This could be an artifact of the library you're using, as the API seems to have no problem with this character in the sheet name.

Comment: I'm using the Java libraries provided by Google. The only Scala code here is my own. The Java library I'm using is `com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev612-1.25.0`

Comment: Can't seem to get this to replicate. What if you try `"'foo \+ bar (yay)'!A2:Z"`?

Comment: I'm having exact same issue with characters such as + and / in the RANGE (sheet name), such as:  sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetID}/values/NY+POINTS?key={key}

Answer (score 0):

i've hit this same bug - also using java libraries, and trying to reference a sheet named "Week 1+2".. i tried the "'Week 1+2'!A2:Z" idea but java didn't like it. i then tried "'Week1\+2'!A2:Z" and it compiled, but got an "Unable to parse range 'Week 1\ 2' error. it's like (as someone pointed out) the '+' gets translated to a space.  I saw elsewhere someone was having an issue with a - in the name too?

** NOT AN ANSWER!!! tried to add as a comment to above but it won't let me**

interesting fact -> i tested the python library to read the sheet, and it accepts the sheetname with an embedded + quite happily.  so this would appear to be a java thing....

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work.

When a sheet name is used in an API call as the RANGE, such as `sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetID}/values/SHEET_NAME_AS_RANGE?key={key}`, the trick is to NOT use single quotes around the range name AND to use encodeURIComponent on the sheet name.

So, for example a sheet with a name of **NY/POINTS+AndSpace Here** would get encoded as **NY%2FPOINTS%2BAndSpace%20Here** and look like this in the example I gave:

```
sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetID}/values/NY%2FPOINTS%2BAndSpace%20Here?key={key}
```

That should mean the OP would be able to use the following:

```
String sheetName = "foo + bar (yay)" 
String range = encodeURIComponent(sheetName) + "!A2:Z"
```

(I only tested this using the sheet name by itself as the RANGE, not including the A2:Z part, so including that would need to be confirmed).