# get googlesheets cells with name sheet with accents

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I try to use the gradle exemple to get googlessheets cells and get error with the tab name with diacritics ("Opérations 2023") because the name is in french.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java
the error is below.

```
    {
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Unable to parse range: Op%C3%A9rations%202023!A2%3AE2",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Unable to parse range: Op%C3%A9rations%202023!A2%3AE2",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

The request is

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "ID";
    final String range = "Opérations 2023!A2:E2";
    Sheets service =
        new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
        .get(spreadsheetId, range)
        .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Name, Major");
      for (List row : values) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do please ?

Comment: Do you have more than one Sheet(tab) in your Spreadsheet? Have you tried with another sheet and see if that way works?

Comment: yes there are several, but it's always the first on the left that I aim for.
if I change the name by removing the accented characters it works, but I can't impose names without accents

Comment: In your script, when `final String range = "Opérations 2023!A2:E2";` is modified to `final String range = "'Opérations 2023'!A2:E2";`, will the error be removed? Or, from `but it's always the first on the left that I aim for.`, in this case, how about modifying from `final String range = "Opérations 2023!A2:E2";` to `final String range = "A2:E2";`? In this case, the 1st tab is always used. But, if these were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike
the second solution, without tab's name works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

I tested with Sheets API [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) and I had no issues using it with sheet named "Opérations 2023" so it seems is not issue with the API but character encoding in Java.

I'm not an expert in Java, but while doing research, I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64690285/17926478) and it shows the same error when using Java while doing it with Python it seems to work with no issue.

As a workaround, if the sheet you're aiming to is the first one in your Worksheet, then you can just omit the name of the Sheet and set the range to: `"A2:E2"`, this will aim the default sheet which is the first one in your Worksheet.